# Script cannot pick a file a second before execution

Tags: shell, cron, find

I have a script which runs every 15 minutes (checks if a new file is present and emails it) [00, 15, 30, 45]

Sometimes there are files being transferred to this location at the very last second (HH:MM:59seconds)

E.g.

Let's say file modified timestamp is (16:14:59)
Script next run is (16:15:00)

The script is not being able to pick that file so is never sent via email
Part of the code:

```
check=`find . -mmin -15`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you schedule your script to start at `16:15:00.0000000`, it will not start and finish in that exact nanosecond. Likewise, disk writes are not atomic, and starting to write a file at `16:14:59.9999999` does not mean it'll finish and have a timestamp before `16:15:00`.

It will take hundreds or maybe thousands of milliseconds before all the OS processes are executed, initialized and scheduled, and all the disk reads finish. The exact time it takes to finish this is unpredictable.

That means that one of your jobs may run at `16:15:00.13` while the next runs at `16:30:01.22`, leaving a second long gap where you can lose files.

Instead of checking "modified in the last 15 minutes" you should check for "modified since the last run of the script" (keeping track of the last processed filename or modification date), or at the very least, "modified on or after 16:15:00 but strictly before 16:30:00".

Comment: Or alternatively, after you transmit a large-ish `myfile.dat`, also create an empty `myfile.dat.done`, and have your pickup script key off those files instead... Several other possible approaches exist, as well.

Comment: Or move the done files to a "done" directory, or keeping everything in a database instead.